# Extension of cocountable sigma algebra with the counting measure.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, outer-measure, measurable-sets

> Let $(X,v,S_0)$ a measure space and define $$\mu^*(E)=\inf\{\sum_nv(A_n):A_n \in S_0,E \subseteq \bigcup_nA_n\}$$
>
> It is easy to see that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure and is called $\textbf{the outer measure induced by}$ $v$.
>
> Also again it is not difficult to prove that $\mu^*(E)=\min\{v(A):A \supseteq E\}$
>
> We denote $\Sigma_{\mu^*}$ the Caratheodory sigma algebra of $\mu^*-$measurable sets.
>
> Now with some work it is proved that if $\mu$ (the restriction of $\mu^*$ to $\Sigma_{\mu^*}$) is sigma finite then $(X,\Sigma_{\mu^*},\mu)$ is the completion of $(X,v,S_0)$

Now assume that $X$ is an uncountable set and  $S_0=\{A \subseteq X: \text{$A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable}\}$ and $v=$counting measure $|A|$

$X$ is not sigma finite with respect to this measure since it is uncountable.

I want to prove that $\Sigma_{\mu^*}=P(X)$ where $m^*$ is the outer measure induced by the counting measure.

Here is my work:

Clearly $(X,|\cdot|,S_0)$ is a measure space.

Now let $A \subseteq X$ and $E \subseteq X$

We always have the inequality $\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(E \cap A)+\mu^*(E \cap A^c)$

So if $E$ is infinite exists $B \in S_0$ such that $B \supset E$ and  $+\infty=|B|=\mu^*(E) \leq\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(E \cap A)+\mu^*(E \cap A^c)$

Thus the equality is satisfied with like this: $+\infty=+\infty$

Now assume that $E$ is finite.

Then  $$\mu^*(E)=|E|=|E\cap A|+|E \cap A^c| = \mu(A \cap E)+\mu(E \cap A^c)=\mu^*(A \cap E)+\mu^*(E \cap A^c)$$
since $E,A \cap E,A^c \cap E$ are finite sets so belong to $S_0$.

In every case the desired equality is satisfied,thus $\Sigma_{\mu^*}=P(X)$

Is this correct,or am i missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is uncountable then the counting measure $\nu$ on the collection of countable and cocountable sets is not $\sigma$-finite so that identification with completion is not okay here.

Anyway, a counting measure is always complete (already). This because its only null-set is the empty set (which belongs to every $\sigma$-algebra).

---

**edit**:

Any [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure)  $\mu^*$ on a set $X$ is a function on $\wp(X)$ with special properties and induces a complete measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_{\mu^*}$.

This complete measure is then $\mu^*$ itself but restricted to this $\sigma$-algebra and $A$ is an element of $\Sigma_{\mu^*}$ iff:$$\forall E\in\wp(X)\;[\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^{\complement})]\tag1$$

If we observe that $\mu^*$ is already a measure itself on $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(X)$ then from that we can draw the immediate conclusion that $(1)$ is satisfied for all $A\in\wp(X)$ so that  $\Sigma_{\mu^*}=\wp(X)$ and the complete measure induced by $\mu^*$ is just $\mu^*$ itself.

You are in that situation here because it is easy to verify that the map that sends finite sets to their cardinality and sends infinite sets to $+\infty$ is indeed a measure on $\wp(X)$.

So your proof (which is okay) is a bit redundant.

Comment: I want to know if my proof that $\Sigma_{\mu^*}=P(X)$ is correct. I know that $S_0$ is complete with the counting measure

Comment: That is indeed the case here and your proof is okay. I will delete this answer within a while. Actually it is enough already to observe that the map that sends finite sets to their cardinality and infinite sets to $+\infty$ is a measure on $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(X)$ and coincides with the counting measure on $S_0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..you can elaborate more on your answer and add context,and i will accept it. you do not have to remove it..i added the tag of proof verification so it makes sence

Comment: I have added something to my answer.